# List comprehension / loop confusion

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

I'm not sure how to word this.. but I have an example and an easy explanation of what I'm trying to do..

Working:

```
for characters in [world.characters for world in self.worlds]:
    for character in characters:
        print(character.name)
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
for characters in [world.characters for world in self.worlds]:
    for character in characters:
        print("Character {0} in World {1}".format(character.name, world.name))
```

So I want to be able to access `world` from my list comprehension inside my loop scope. I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: what's doesn't work with the code you've suggested. Do you get any errors or traceback that you could share (if so please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47523123/edit) the question and copy and paste the entire error/traceback text )?

Comment: `world` would not be within the scope of my loop, since it is defined only inside the list comprehension. so I get unresolved reference / NameError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for world in self.worlds:
    for character in world.characters:
        print("Character {0} in World {1}".format(character.name, world.name))
```

Comment: Probably your easiest answer ever! I don't know what was going on in my mind.. working with list comprehensions for a while and had somehow created a requirement that didn't exist (that it couldn't be done in a conventional loop, worlds -> world -> characters -> character)

Sorry for wasting your time all.

Comment: No problem. I have been struggling for the last couple of years (pushed by another programmer who is very Pythonic) to get used to list comprehensions. But sometimes regular loops are just easier. Actually the whole thing probably could be done in a nested list comprehension, but it doesn't seem worth the effort.